# Usar google maps con datos traidos por ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, function

estoy trayendo datos desde una api externa con ajax, la cual me proporciona la longitud y latitud pero al momento de aplicarlo al google maps no me lee los datos. Este es el codigo de la consulta ajax

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://quasar.e-htl.com.br/booking/detail",
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + xmiCookie},
            data: datos,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                swal({
                    title: "Procesando..",
                    text: "Recibiendo los datos, espere por favor...",
                    icon: "success",
                    buttons: false,
                    closeOnClickOutside: false,
                    closeOnEsc: false
                });
            },
            success: function ( json ) {
                 jQuery.map(json, function (val) {
                 var hlatitud = val.attributes.Hotel.HotelLatitude;
                 var hlongitud = val.attributes.Hotel.hotelLongitude;
              });                
            },
            error: function ( ) {
            }
             });
```

Tengo al final de la pagina dentro de un script la function del google maps

```
        function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: hlatitud, lng: hlongitud};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapSingle'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
        });
    }
```

y ademas el llamado a la funcion de google maps

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

debes de incluir la función en el resultado del request de AJAX

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: "https://quasar.e-htl.com.br/booking/detail",
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + xmiCookie},
            data: datos,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
                swal({
                    title: "Procesando..",
                    text: "Recibiendo los datos, espere por favor...",
                    icon: "success",
                    buttons: false,
                    closeOnClickOutside: false,
                    closeOnEsc: false
                });
            },
            success: function ( json ) {
                 jQuery.map(json, function (val) {
                 var hlatitud = val.attributes.Hotel.HotelLatitude;
                 var hlongitud = val.attributes.Hotel.hotelLongitude;
                 initMap(hlatitud ,hlongitud )
              });                
            },
            error: function ( ) {
            }
             });
```

y pesarla por parámetros los dos valores a la función

```
function initMap(hlatitud,hlongitud) {
        var uluru = {lat: hlatitud, lng: hlongitud};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapSingle'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
        });
    }
```

Comment: No me funciono, ya que me dice que la funcion no esta definida o ReferenceError: initMap is not defined